# Passing argument to thread by std::ref in slows down execution?

Tags: c++

I have a question.

I was today playing with threads. I wanted to make sure that on 2-core processor, when I split a task into 2 parts I will get a near 2x increase in execution time (no locks involved here).

I wanted to use simple mechanism without any fancy things like async etc., just a simple thread running a function executing some very simple caclulations. 
I wrote a function summing integers from a given range and saving the result in the ouptput parameter passed by reference.

I added measuring time and run the example with 1 thread.

Then I changed the program to run the same function in 2 separate threads, with split range. Of course in order to return the result to the main thread by reference I had to use std::ref (to be able to create a thread). I was much surpriced when I noticed that the execution time of the program almost did not change at all.

Then I created a new function doing the same but acepting reference_wrapper and run it in the 1-thread program. The execution time now was 2x the time of the program with 2 threads. So I somehow confirmed that the 2-thread program like this may get 2x speed-up compared to 1-thread program, when they both use std::ref. But the bad thing is that I can run 1-thread program without bothering of using std::ref and this program runs as fast as 2-thread program with std::ref.

Below I paste the program containing all 3 options and the output on my 2-core machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int work(uint64_t b, uint64_t e, uint64_t& sum)
{
    for (int i = b; i < e; ++i)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
}

int work1(uint64_t b, uint64_t e, std::reference_wrapper<uint64_t> sum)
{
    for (int i = b; i < e; ++i)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
}

int main() {
    uint64_t sum = 0u;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    work(0, 1000000000000000000, sum);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    cout << "one thread, duration = " << duration << endl;

    sum = 0u;
    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    work1(0, 1000000000000000000, std::ref(sum));
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    cout << "one thread, std::ref, duration = " << duration << endl;

    uint64_t sum21 = 0u;
    uint64_t sum22 = 0u;
    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    thread th1(work, 0, 500000000000000000, std::ref(sum21));
    thread th2(work, 500000000000000000, 1000000000000000000, std::ref(sum22));
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    sum = sum21 + sum22;
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    cout << "two threads, std::ref, duration = " << duration << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
one thread, duration = 7777627
one thread, std::ref, duration = 17021098
two threads, std::ref, duration = 7426095
```

**My question is: why does std::ref slow things down so much?**

Regards

YK

Comment: This is likely not doing what you think: `for (int i = b; i < e; ++i)` e is `uint64_t`, how can `int` i ever reach it?

Comment: You are right, I had a bug there, but that does not change the thing about std::ref. I corrected the loop and changed the range (working on u64 takes more time), but the times say the same as before. one thread, duration = 51747597
one thread, std::ref, duration = 95675400
two threads, std::ref, duration = 46117458

Comment: I run this a couple more times and the results are better for std::ref. one thread, duration = 52347623
one thread, std::ref, duration = 96159456
two threads, std::ref, duration = 32636795. I also did a version with no passing output parameter, and it runs the same fast as with std::ref. So to sum this up: It seems that std::ref behaves OK.